# How to create a dynamic if condition

Tags: c#, visual-studio, if-statement

Hello i'm trying to write a search tool for filenames allowing to search with multiple words.
At the moment i can just search for one word but i want to filter my results with more words combined.

Here is my code so far:

```
public List<String> startYareSearch(string query, string source)
{      
    List<String> SearchResultList = new List<String>();
    List<String> FileNameList = getFileNames(source);

    foreach (string fileName in FileNameList)
    {
        if (fileName.IndexOf(query, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
            SearchResultList.Add(fileName);
            continue;
        }
    }

    return SearchResultList;
}
```

T think that i need a function which receives the queries from an array and generate a dynamic if condition.

For an example:

```
String[] queries=  new string[] { "Tobias", ".txt"};   
String fileName= "blablaTobiasbla.txt";

if (fileName.IndexOf("Tobias", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 && fileName.IndexOf(".txt", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
{
    SearchResultList.Add(fileName);
    continue;
}
```

is it possible to create an if condition dynamically? Do you know a better solution?

Comment: What is wrong with putting a foreach inside your outer foreach in the first example. Linq would also be an alternative.

Comment: I think you need codeDome: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, you can. create an expression as a Func, then pass in that inside your linq call either one of them (Find, Where, First, etc.). It will be something like func = () => some expression;, FileNameList.Find(func);

Comment: could you give me an example

Comment: The problem as far as I see it is that your method needs to accept a parameter which is a collection of queries rather than a single query string. You can then enumerate those queries as the above poster suggested and populate them into a secondary collection.

Comment: I think what you're looking for here is something along the lines of the [specification pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern).

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ to do something like:

```
var result= FileNameList.Where(f=>queries.Contains(f));
```

Comment: i want to filter my search with more than one query

Comment: resull is null. do you know what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this if you like

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> fileNames = new List<string> {"blablaTobiasbla.txt"};
        List<string> queries = new List<string> {"Tobias", ".txt"};

        var results = SearchFileNames(fileNames, queries);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> SearchFileNames(IEnumerable<string> fileNames, IEnumerable<string> queries)
    {
        return fileNames.Where(fileName => queries.All(fileName.Contains));
    }
}
```

This SearchFileNames method checks that all items in the queries list contains in the file name then, returns a collection if there are any.

Comment: result is null. do you know what the problem is

Comment: result is null because there was no result found in the "Where(...)"  code.